# Drop all nan value in Series

Tags: python, pandas, ipython

**I have try to drop a nan value like so**

```
import pandas
data = pandas.read_json("data.json")
lat = data["Latitude"]
lng = data["Longitude"]
shop = data["Store - Business Name"]
df2 = lat.dropna(axis=0, how='any')
df1 = pandas.to_numeric(df2, errors='coerce')

print(df1)
```

what am i missing, because i still get nan value in my panda series.

Comment: Pandas can be quite tricky to start with. What you can do to drop rows with missing Latitude values is simply `df = df.dropna(axis= 0, subset= ['Latitude'])`. In this case, the subset parameter is the list of columns that are included in the procedure.

Comment: Can you accept the question since it works?

Answer (score 3):

`lat` is a series in your data, if you have even only one `nan` value in your series ,`lat`, then you will loose all of your series. 
Another problem might be in the `lat` column values might not be suitable for converting to `pd.to_numeric` such as `"1,2"` (not `"1.2"`), `"a"`, `"nan"` etc. Then you will loose your series again. 
Therefore:

Check:
`len(lat.dropna()) == len(lat)` 
if it is `True` then check:

```
len(df2[df2.str.contains(",")]) > 0
```

I hope it works!

Answer (score 0):

df2 = lat.dropna(axis=0, how='any') it is deleting entire row which is having any of the nan values instead use 
df2 = lat.dropna(axis=0, how='all') if want to drop all the rows which are having nan values.